# Adding extended user class fields to payload data in access token

Tags: python, django

I extended my user class to include other fields (city, country, bio). I would like to pass these down along to customizing my JWT access_token to include these fields as a payload in addition to username.

This is what I have in my models.py (extending my user class):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

#extending user model to include
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

serializers.py:

```
#changed from serializers.HyperLinked to ModelSerializer
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        #removed url from fields
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'city', 'country', 'bio']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
        }
        def create(self,validated_data):
            user = Profile.objects.create_user(
                                            username=validated_data['username'],
                                            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
                                            last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
                                            city=validated_data['city'],
                                            country=validated_data['country'],
                                            bio=validated_data['bio'],
                                            email=validated_data['email'])
            user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            user.save()
            return user

#customizing the payload we get from our access tokens
class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        token['username'] = user.username
        token['first_name'] = user.first_name
        token['last_name'] = user.last_name
        token['country'] = user.profile.country
        token['city'] = user.profile.city
        token['bio'] = user.profile.bio
        return token
```

and api.py

```
#Register API
class RegisterApi(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    #remove this if it doesn't work
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    def post(self, request, *args,  **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "message": "User Created Successfully.  Now perform Login to get your token",
        })
```

When I attempt to login now I get the error message:

```
AttributeError at /api/token/
'User' object has no attribute 'profile'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/
```

Comment: `profile` should be lowercased when you access the relationship: `user.profile.country`.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Thanks, tried that, updated my question to reflect the changes I made

Comment: Probably this user doesn't have profile at all? Are you sure profile for the user exists in DB? If it doesn't django raises attribute error exception.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner correct me if i'm wrong, but if I have blank=True for some attributes (city,country, bio) that means that a user profile can be created while these remain blank?

Comment: Correct but for OneToOne field it's a bit different: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField Check this part of the doc: A RelatedObjectDoesNotExist exception is raised when accessing the reverse relationship if an entry in the related table doesn’t exist. Not sure if the problem related to this though.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Thanks for the link and just to make sure I'm getting things right. Shouldn't a corresponding entry be created in Profile when I create a user since Profile and User have a one to one relationship?

Comment: No, it won't be created automatically. You need to create profile entity separately each time you create a new user.